# Make a WebView flutter app with different urls everytime using python

Tags: python, flutter, dart, webview, automation

I want to create a python form with a textfiled and a button where a user will enter his/her link and it will create a webview flutter apk for that url. I want advice from the community if it is possible or not. If it is possible, please let me know how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can achieve this via using a remote server. You can create a connection between your python program and the server, and you can create the apk file in server and send it to your python program.

Comment: What tool shall I use to create apk on server?